# Find and replace pattern inside BigQuery string

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my BigQuery table. I am trying to find out the URLs that were displayed but not viewed.

```
create table dataset.url_visits(ID INT64 ,displayed_url string , viewed_url string);

select * from dataset.url_visits;

ID        Displayed_URL              Viewed_URL 
1         url11,url12                url12
2         url9,url12,url13           url9
3         url1,url2,url3             NULL
```

In this example, I want to display

```
ID        Displayed_URL              Viewed_URL      unviewed_URL
1         url11,url12                url12           url11
2         url9,url12,url13           url9            url12,url13
3         url1,url2,url3             NULL            url1,url2,url3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the each string into an array and unnest them. Do a `case` to check if the items are in each other and combine to an array or a string.

```
Select ID, string_agg(viewing ) as viewed,
    string_agg(not_viewing ) as not_viewed,
    array_agg(viewing ignore nulls) as viewed_array
from (
Select ID , 
    case when display in unnest(split(Viewed_URL)) then  display else null end as viewing,
    case when display in unnest(split(Viewed_URL)) then  null else display end as not_viewing,    
from (
Select 1 as ID, "url11,url12" as Displayed_URL, "url12" as Viewed_URL UNION ALL
Select 2, "url9,url12,url13", "url9" UNION ALL
Select 3, "url1,url2,url3",  NULL UNION ALL 
Select 4, "url9,url12,url13", "url9,url12" 
),unnest(split(Displayed_URL)) as display
)
group by 1
```

Comment: I have a question. we are using group by column here for the string_agg function to work. Is there anyway to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you., I used your query as a template and now I got the correct results

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *, (
  select string_agg(url)
  from unnest(split(Displayed_URL)) url 
  where url != ifnull(Viewed_URL, '')
  ) unviewed_URL
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That works. one question I have     .  In the filter clause    where url != ifnull(Viewed_URL, '')  here we don't unnest and split viewed_url . Bigquery automatically does that ?

Comment: You don’t need to unnest viewed_url as it is just a string and not an array

Comment: If the viewed_url is also an array we have to unnest it correct. for example. displayed_url=url1,url2,url3,url4   viewed_url=url3,url5   .  we have to get url1,url2,url4  as our final output . we have to unnest viewed_url and then do an string_agg at the higher level . Kindly clarify.

Comment: I have posted a new question . Thank you.